# Activate Night Shift and Invert Colors simultaneously

Tags: macos, night-shift

It seems like on both iOS and macOS, you must either choose to activate Night Shift or Invert Colors—but not both at the same time.

Due to iOS being so restricted, it seems as though (at least without a jailbreak) there can be no workaround to allow activating both features simultaneously. However, on macOS, I assume there must be a way.

One possibility is by using a third-party program such as f.lux, which *can* be used alongside Invert Colors on macOS (this is also possible on iOS, albeit if you have a jailbreak or are able to side load a similar app). However, I would prefer using Night Shift to f.lux.

Is there a way to "trick" macOS and activate both at the same time?

Comment: I'm not sure how this works but have you tried the screen accessibility features, and see if it works with that? This article shows one example, but I found that there were a couple of accessibility features that would reduce light https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/make-iphone-display-dimmer-than-low-brightness/

Comment: Just as a heads-up, as of Monterey there is finally no way to combine invert (neither “classic” nor “smart”) with either night shift (simply not an option) or flux (screen will turn blue). It seems like dark theme is the only way for the time being.

Comment: That's sad to hear! I remember it working with f.lux in the past. At least dark mode + Dark Reader on Chromium alleviates the need for this, but in some apps without an implemented dark mode it's still nice to be able to combine invert colors + Night Shift